# Treat only StyleCop warning as errors

Tags: .net-core, stylecop

To treat all warnings as errors it's enought to add, to add this to .NET Core project:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  <WarningsAsErrors />
</PropertyGroup>
```

but I want to treat only StyleCop warnings as errors, not others. How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you change StyleCop setup so that it reports Errors instead of warnings? Won't is solve the problem?